# Unable to Authenticate with Google BigQuery

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a sample BigQuery query using a Python Client that I downloaded from the Google Site (modified with my client secrets, project info, etc.), but am unable to get passed the browser page that is requesting access.  I've tried several browsers including Chrome and Firefox.  I am on a MAC if that matters.

I've tried both the native google client sample as well as Pandas GBQ API.

When I execute either of the API samples, a page is rendered in the browser basically asking that the client API is requesting permission to "View and manage your data in Google BigQuery".

When I click Accept, a new page is rendered with an error that indicates no data was returned from the server.

I cannot tell if this is an issue with Google or my local network blocking.

I would like to know what might be going on or how I can troubleshoot this issue so I can authenticate/authorize and run queries through my python client.

Thanks,
J.D.

Comment: What happens when you use the command line client that Google provides for BigQuery? If the same problem occurs there, then I would investigate your local networking config. Instructions for installing the client are here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#installation

Answer (score 1):

The issue was environmental.  My browser was not recognizing localhost, so when I manually modified the url to reference the ip, 127.0.0.1, then the authorization succeeded.

Thanks for the responses.